# In an ASP.NET Core MVC Razor view, issue related to @model IEnumerable<Namespace.Model> Vs @model<Namespace.Model>

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

In an ASP.NET Core MVC Razor view, I have 2 forms. One input form is used to populate 2 dropdown lists as ajax modelpopup and saving values in database. Another form is used to display the related values as datatable in same view.

When I try to populate data table by `@foreach(var item in Model)` loop by declaring `@model IEnumerable<Namespace.Model>` in view, it works fine for assigning value to datatable controls.

But other form having dropdownlist shows error. Not able to declare asp-for for select control.

```
<div class="form-group"> @{var Jsonlist = new electList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["JsonPropVD"], "Value", "Key");}
    <select asp-items="Jsonlist" asp-for="ClientCatalog" class="form-control"></select>
</div> 


public void GetJsonProperties()
{
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfosSM = typeof(SMJsonModel).GetProperties();

    if (propertyInfosSM != null)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> Jsondictresults = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfoJson in propertyInfosSM)
        {
            Jsondictresults.Add(propertyInfoJson.Name, propertyInfoJson.Name);
        }

        ViewBag.VBJsonProp = Jsondictresults.Keys;
        ViewData["JsonPropVD"] = Jsondictresults;
    }            
}
```

When I change from `@model IEnumerable<Namespace.Model>` to `@model<Namespace.Model>`, I am able to access dropdownlist in the form but `@foreach(var item in Model)` shows an error. So I need to populate with viewbag.

```
<tbody>
@foreach (K360Master Mappeddata in ViewBag.K360MappedData)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Mappeddata.Id</td>
        <td>@Mappeddata.ClientCatalog</td>
        <td>@Mappeddata.K360catalog</td>
        <td>
            <button id="btnDelete" asp-action="DeletePost" asp-route-Id="@Mappeddata.Id" class="btn btn-danger mr-3">Delete</button>
        </td>                         
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

It’s not advisable to use viewbag and viewdata. Please guide me how to achieve this by using strongly typed view for the above requirement.

Comment: Btw Type.GetProperties will never return null. It will return either an empty array (no properties) or an array of the appropriate size. So, always the number of properties (0 or N)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `asp-for` tag helper in the select tag, and manually set its id and name

```
<select asp-items="Jsonlist" id="ClientCatalog" name="ClientCatalog" class="form-control"></select>
```